# mysql sub-select on a text column in MySQL 5.6 not returning results

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-5.6

I have an audit query like the following that I use to audit the table level permissions for users I have in MySQL:

```
SELECT -- the list of privileges for tables
mt.host `host`,
mt.user `user`,
CONCAT(mt.Db, '.', mt.Table_name) `Tables`,
REPLACE(mt.Table_priv, ',', ', ') AS `Privileges`
FROM
mysql.tables_priv mt
WHERE
mt.Table_name IN
(SELECT
DISTINCT
t.table_name `tables`
FROM
information_schema.tables AS t
WHERE
t.table_type IN
('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VIEW', 'TEMPORARY', '') OR
t.table_type <> 'VIEW' AND
t.create_options IS NOT NULL
)
```

The query was working great until I upgraded from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.6. Now it doesn't work. Is there some kind of problem in MySQL 5.6 with a sub SELECT on a text column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this could be your problem:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77191
Using the workaround at the bottom I was able to get this to work.

```
set optimizer_switch='semijoin=off';
```

Comment: Thanks for finding that so quickly!

Comment: I later realized that work around may not always be at the bottom of that bug report...